# mount: /dev/sda1: can't read superblock

Tags: linux, железо, mount

Подключаю HD к Orange Pi PC. Не маунтит. Пытаюсь сам замаунтить

```
root@orangepi:/mnt# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/Drive/
mount: /dev/sda1: can't read superblock
```

При попытке fsck

```
root@orangepi:/mnt# fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read  while trying to open /dev/sda1
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

На ПК работает норм. Как на Шиндоус, так и на федоре

fdisk вообще его не видит, лол

```
root@orangepi:/mnt# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8018 MB, 8018460672 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 244704 cylinders, total 15661056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x52359aec

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1           40960      124927       41984   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2          124928    15661055     7768064   83  Linux
```

Comment: Вы логи загрузки лучше смотрите, особенно часть которая за подъем sata отвечает. ну и /proc/partitions гляньте

Comment: В `syslog`' е много сообщений, вроде `critical target error, dev sda, sector 0`. Т.е. мб диск крашнутый, но `mount` должен же работать, даже если так

Comment: Ну если он даже сектор 0 не может прочитать, в котором таблица разделов лежит, то как он узнает где раздел находится. И может не с диском, а что то не так с sata интерфейсом или драйвера не могут с ним нормально работать

Comment: Стоп. А у вас диск то раскручивается ? откуда вы для диска 12V берете, на Orange как я понял 12V не присутствуют.

Comment: Лол, там не 12В нужно. Это обычный внешний ЖД. Питание 5В. Но я его забросил, взял другой и норм)

Comment: иногда кстати встречается несовместимость конкретных дисков с конкретными контроллерами, точнее их драйверами в ядре, я сталкивался.